# Susy - Prevent Grid from creating a line break during transition

Tags: css, sass, susy

I noticed on my phone, using this menu:

[image]

It's obvious that it exceeded the size of the row from this picture and it creates a line break during the transition, however, on desktop, it does not.
It should stay in the same row during the transition:

[image]

Here is my sass:

```
.h5-menu { //h5 menu styling
  @include span(4 inside);
  @include transition(0.25s ease all);
  font-weight:400; //override default 300
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:$lb300;
  padding:{
    bottom:25px;
    top:25px;
  }
  background-color:$lb700;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.h5-selected { //css class to add when option is selected
  @include span(8 inside);
  background-color:$lb500!important;
  color:$white!important;
}
```

On the parent element, I set the layout to have no gutters.

I noticed that when I remove the transition, there's no line break; however, it looks choppy, is there anyway I can make this work with a transition?

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrqKrX)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `of 12` after you mention how many columns you want like...

```
@include span(4 of 12 inside);
```

If it still doesn't solve... Kindly consider preparing a codepen/jsfiddler or share the link 2 your live site ;-)

**EDIT**
If that doesn't solve...

1. Check if version of Susy is atleast v2+
2. Inspect the elements to see if any horizontal margin is applied, I've had thousands of issues where margin turned out to b the culprit.
3. `box-sizing` for both elements should be `border-box`.

**Fix for subpixel issues**
It seems like it's a sub pixel issue... try this css...

```
.h5-selected {
  ...
  margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, here's the codepen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrqKrX, it seems to be working on mobile with the codepen. I'm hosting my site locally, and I'm accessing it from my phone, I'm completely lost as to why this isn't working.

Comment: Try installing latest susy ( atleast use v2+ ) if you don't have it already, Also try reproducing the issue in codepen... You can also inspect the element to check any horizontal margin being adding. Also keep an eye on `box-sizing` it should be `border-box` ( or even `padding-box` would do if you don't have a border ).

Comment: I'm using susy v2.2.12, added box-sizing, and there is no margin. :(

Comment: Ohh... Okay... lets try reproduce the issue in codepen... Add all your `css` to codepen. If issue is still not reproduced add a screenshot of your page ( so that we know what elements surround it... ) to your question...

Comment: I updated the codepen with all of the sass, and it works on codepen, but not on my website.

Comment: Super, that worked. There's just a small white space, but I don't think it's a big deal.